# How to filter N/A Values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, I am using a Card Visual.

On this visual, I have a dax measure that I created. The DAX Measure is created like this:

```
gp_viewing_rate_cy = IF (
    [gp_CntViewedByStudent_CY_Adjusted] == 0 || [gp_CntViewedByStudent_PY_Adjusted] == 0 || 
    MAX('Highlights'[gp_exempt_status_cy]) == "exempt" || MAX('Highlights'[gp_exempt_status_py]) == "exempt"
    , "N/A"
    ,DIVIDE([gp_CntViewedByStudent_CY_Adjusted],SUM('Highlights'[gp_CntStudents_CY]),"N/A")
  )
```

This calculated measure is used as the field for my card metric. Right now, it displays N/A as a value.

I want to filter out all of the N/A values so that the value is some number instead.

When I drag `gp_viewing_rate_cy` to the filters, it won't let me filter.

Why is this and what can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the parameters passed in the IF condition is 4 instead of 3. The correct syntax is IF(Condition, If True, If False). The result generated is not correct because of which even if you are dragging it in the filters, the option to select the values is unavailable.